# What is a receiver in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am reading [You Don't Know JS: ES6 & Beyond](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/cc82d7c8f4872ceee87a5c3b193ee846c6ab0ecc/es6%20%26%20beyond) and found some confused wording like:

> We declare a `get(..)` handler as a named method on the handler object (second argument to `Proxy(..)`), which receives a reference to the target object (`obj`), the key property name (`"a"`), and the self/receiver/proxy (`pobj`).

My question is, what does "receiver" mean above and where does its name come from?

It seems like if I have an object "a" with a member function "jump":

```
var a = { jump: function() { console.log('jump!'); } };
```

If I run `a.jump();` then "a" is the receiver.

Is that how it works?

For people who read the same book: when you come to the [Proxy First, Proxy Last](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/cc82d7c8f4872ceee87a5c3b193ee846c6ab0ecc/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch7.md#proxy-first-proxy-last) section, you can add one line in the code to get a more clear picture about the context in the "get" trap:

```
var handlers = {
    get(target, key, context) {
        console.log(greeter === context); //true, this line added
        return function() {
            context.speak(key + "!");
        };
    }
},
catchall = new Proxy({}, handlers),
var greeter = {
    speak(who = "someone") {
        console.log("hello", who);
    }
};

// setup `greeter` to fall back to `catchall`
Object.setPrototypeOf(greeter, catchall);

greeter.speak();                // hello someone
greeter.speak("world");       // hello world

greeter.everyone();             // hello everyone!
```

As you can see, thanks to the naming of the third argument of the "get" trap above, "context", the receiver can vary according to lexical code -- `greeter.everyone();`. Please refer to Oriol's very detailed answer below for a better understanding.

Comment: krave is talking about this book: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_u1rzdqYCnzRUlHcV9sQVpTMFE/view see page 182 at the top.

Comment: in the real book, its on page 211

Comment: edit with right target to online resource.

Comment: I think the term `receiver` comes from Message Passing style.  This simply means the object that receives the message that has been passed.  `a` in this case **receives** the message to process the `jump` method etc.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The receiver is the object in which the property lookup happens.

So yes, if you use `a.jump`, `a` is the receiver.

The concept is only relevant when you can execute arbitrary code when that property lookup happens. Basically, that means:

- Accessor properties.

  You can access the receiver by using `this` inside the getter or setter. The receiver will usually be the object in which you defined the property, or another object which inherits from it.

  ```
  var target = {
    get getReceiver() { return this; }
  };
  target.getReceiver; // target
  var inherits = Object.create(target);
  inherits.getReceiver; // inherits
  ```

  A built-in example is `__proto__`, defined as a property of `Object.prototype` but expected to be got or set on other objects (receivers).
- Proxy objects

  Proxy objects allow you to define `get` or `set` traps, which run a function when you attempt to get or set any property to the proxy. The receiver is provided as an argument of that function. The receiver will usually the Proxy object itself, or an object which inherits from it.

  ```
  var proxy = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(target, property, receiver) {
      return receiver;
    }
  });
  proxy.getReceiver; // proxy
  var inherits = Object.create(proxy);
  inherits.getReceiver; // inherits
  ```

Note you can use [`Reflect.get`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reflect.get) or [`Reflect.set`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reflect.set) to specify arbitrary receivers:

```
Reflect.get(target, "getReceiver", arbitraryValue); // arbitraryValue ¹
Reflect.get(proxy, "getReceiver", arbitraryValue); // arbitraryValue
```

¹ <sub>If the getter was defined in non-strict mode, it will be `Object(arbitraryValue)`</sub>.

The name "receiver" comes from the specification, see [Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)

> - [[Get]]   (*propertyKey*, *Receiver*) → *any*
>
>   Return the value of the property whose key is *propertyKey* from this object. If any ECMAScript code must be executed to retrieve the
>     property value, *Receiver* is used as the **this** value when
>     evaluating the code.
> - [[Set]]   (*propertyKey*, *value*, *Receiver*) → *Boolean*
>
>   Set the value of the property whose key is *propertyKey* to value. If any ECMAScript code must be executed to set the property value,
>     *Receiver* is used as the **this** value when evaluating the code. Returns **true** if the property value was set or **false** if it
>     could not be set.

Comment: just a short question, is there a real every day example?

Comment: @NinaScholz Well, when you use `obj.prop`, `obj` is the receiver. But unless it's a proxy or `prop` has a getter, you can't do anything special with the receiver, so it's not relevant.

Comment: Using `Reflect.get` as just the default for `get` on a proxy results in errors when trying to access a property defined on the prototype of the target that the proxy wraps. What's the usage of receiver inside proxy intercepts?

Comment: @Oriol So if `a = Array(0)`, then is `a` the receiver in `a.push(0)`?

Answer (score 24):

I spent some time trying to figure out exactly what this "receiver" could and would be used for when used with `Reflect.get`, and, perhaps unsuprisingly, it's all just as [MDN explains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get):

> `receiver` *Optional*
> The value of `this` provided for the call to target if a getter is encountered. When used with `Proxy`, it can be an object that inherits from `target`.

Basically, as far as I could assess, the decisive role it plays with `Reflect.get` is when used to access *getter* properties. For instance, the `Reflect.get` call in the following snippet will return `2`, and not `undefined`.

```js
const obj = { get foo() { return this.bar; } };
Reflect.get(obj, "foo", { bar: 2 });
```

The actual getter (`get foo()...`) is invoked with `{ bar: 2 }` as the "receiver". Without third argument to `Reflect.get`, the receiver is implied to be the object itself, naturally -- and since it does not have a `bar` property, `undefined` is returned. If it had defined a `bar` property, things are far simpler indeed:

```js
const obj = { bar: 1, get foo() { return this.bar } };
obj.foo; /// evaluates to 1
Reflect.get(obj, "foo"); /// evaluates to 1, equivalent to above
Reflect.get(obj, "foo", { bar: "soap" }) /// evaluates to, guess what, "soap"
```

I don't think there is anything more than that to it, not with `Reflect.get`, anyway.

Comment: It seems that this is rather an expansion of Oriol's answer, but that's awesome to have use-cases as well. Nice answer, +1

Comment: I hope it proves useful. I tried to incorporate a specific example as part of an alternative explanation, after reading comments to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but the responses provided are quite unclear since they fail to provide any useful example that really answer the question "why does the spec even bother with this receiver ?"

Things actually become interesting and start to make sense when you are wrapping a Proxy with another Proxy (or wrapping an object with getters or functions). Here an example of something that is "kind of" believable in real life, that demonstrate how you can combine almost all the cases:

```
const FOOD = Symbol("Food")
const GENERAL = Symbol("General")
const GREEN = Symbol("Green")

class ItemList {
  totalAsFunc(){
    let sum = 0;
    for(const key of Reflect.ownKeys(this)){
      sum += this[key].price
    }
    return sum;
  }

  get total(){
    return this.totalAsFunc();
  }
}

class VATProxyHandler {
  constructor(vatDesc){
    this.vatDesc = vatDesc
  }
  getRate(kind){
    return this.vatDesc[kind] ?? this.vatDesc[GENERAL] ?? 0;
  }
  get(target, prop, recv){
    const original = Reflect.get(target, prop, recv);
    if(original.price !== undefined && original.kind !== undefined) { // If the requested value is not an item, just forward. Else, add vat
      return {
        ...original,
        vat: this.getRate(original.kind) * original.price
      }
    }
    return original;
  }
}


class TaxIncProxyHandler {
  constructor(vatDesc){
    this.vatDesc = vatDesc
  }
  get(target, prop, recv){
    const original = Reflect.get(target, prop, recv);
    if(original.price !== undefined && original.kind !== undefined) {
      return {
        ...original,
        price: original.vat + original.price,
        taxExcluded : original.price
      }
    }
    return original;
  }
}

franceVATHandler = new VATProxyHandler({
  [GENERAL]: 0.20,
  [FOOD]: 0.05,
})

germanyVATHandler = new VATProxyHandler({
  [GENERAL]: 0.19,
  [FOOD]: 0.07,
  [GREEN]: 0,
})

const taxIncHandler = new TaxIncProxyHandler()

const itemList = new ItemList();
itemList.foo = {
  price: 42,
  kind: GENERAL,
}
itemList.bar = {
  price: 21,
  kind: FOOD,
}
itemList.photovoltaicPanel = {
  price: 150,
  kind: GREEN,
}

const itemListFR = new Proxy(new Proxy(itemList, franceVATHandler), taxIncHandler);
const itemListGE = new Proxy(new Proxy(itemList, germanyVATHandler), taxIncHandler);

console.log({
  country:"France",
  foo: itemListFR.foo,
  bar: itemListFR.bar,
  photovoltaicPanel: itemListFR.photovoltaicPanel,
  totalAsFunc: itemListFR.totalAsFunc(),
  total: itemListFR.total,
  rawTotalAsFunc: itemList.totalAsFunc(),
  rawTotal: itemList.total,
})

console.log({
  country:"Germany",
  foo: itemListGE.foo,
  bar: itemListGE.bar,
  photovoltaicPanel: itemListGE.photovoltaicPanel,
  totalAsFunc: itemListGE.totalAsFunc(),
  total: itemListGE.total,
  rawTotalAsFunc: itemList.totalAsFunc(),
  rawTotal: itemList.total,
})
```

To sumup :
The only value you will ever have as `receiver` from javascript is the proxy itself. The only case it is not, is from direct user call to Reflect. Here this trick is used in TaxIncHandler so that VATHandler pass the right `this` to the getter (when Reflect.get is called on a raw Object (i.e. not proxied), and the prop is a getter or a function, then the `this` value is the receiver passed to Reflect.get).

Note also that `this` inside a handler trap is always the handler defining the trap itself. This is used here so that we can retrieve the right VAT amount.