# Weird issue about JavaScript Proxy and getter functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, getter, es6-proxy

The two test cases blow both pass. I simply don't understand the behavior. It seems that JavaScript Proxy cannot trap property getting inside a getter function.

```
test('JS Proxy normal method', () => {
  class Store {
    hidden = false;
    visible() {
      return !this.hidden;
    }
  }
  const accessList: PropertyKey[] = [];
  const proxy = new Proxy<Store>(new Store(), {
    get: (target: any, propertyKey: PropertyKey) => {
      accessList.push(propertyKey);
      return Reflect.get(target, propertyKey);
    },
  });
  expect(proxy.visible()).toBe(true);
  expect(accessList).toEqual(['visible', 'hidden']);
});

test('JS Proxy getter method', () => {
  class Store {
    hidden = false;
    get visible() {
      return !this.hidden;
    }
  }
  const accessList: PropertyKey[] = [];
  const proxy = new Proxy<Store>(new Store(), {
    get: (target: any, propertyKey: PropertyKey) => {
      accessList.push(propertyKey);
      return Reflect.get(target, propertyKey);
    },
  });
  expect(proxy.visible).toBe(true);
  expect(accessList).toEqual(['visible']);
});
```

Comment: Which of the expectations are failing and how?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-9Ac75qj2DogA

Comment: Btw, your `get` trap is not forwarding the `receiver` argument to `Reflect.get`

Comment: @Bergi I expect the two to have identical behavior regarding `get` trap.  Thanks for your comment. You may post an answer instead.

Comment: "Btw, your get trap is not forwarding the receiver argument to Reflect.get" that is the root cause!  Please post an answer and I will accept. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the [receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37563495/1048572) of the property access. The property might be defined on a different object than it is accessed on, and your [`Reflect.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get) call needs to take that into account. In particular, the receiver you get as a [argument of the `get` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) is the proxy itself, and that's also the object you want to evaluate the getter against, so that its `this` value refers to the proxy. However, `Reflect.get(target, propertyKey)` is the same as `target[propertyKey]`, where the `this` value in the getter is set to the `target` and the `.hidden` property access can't be detected by your proxy.