# Is there a functional difference between `Reflect.get()` and regular property access in a `Proxy` handler?

Tags: javascript

[MDN's article on `Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) displays two ways to write [`get()` handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get):

```js
const first = new Proxy(target, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    return target[property];
  }
});

const second = new Proxy(target, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  }
});
```

As far as I've tested, both seem to work as expected for simple cases.

```js
const target = {
  foo: 42
};

const first = new Proxy(target, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    return target[property];
  }
});

const second = new Proxy(target, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  }
});

console.log(first.foo);
console.log(second.foo);
```

Is there a functional difference between the two options? Is there a setup in which one approach works, but the other fails?

Comment: Seems like it could matter because in the first proxy you are skipping the receiver parameter

Comment: It [does make a difference for getters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68968624/1048572).